# Is it possible to have callback to member of template class?

Tags: c++, templates, callback

[image]

Is it possible to have callback to member of template class, as depicted above? I mean, I have some template class, there is defined object of another (non-template) class. That object has another member function. I would like to invoke from that member function the member function of template class. Is it feasible?

Comment: I don't see why not. What problems have you encountered when trying to implement it?

Comment: How is template class different from any other class?

Comment: How can I call the member without knowing the specialization of template?

Comment: Use a lambda and `std::function`.  Then some class can take a `std::function` with the needed signature and any type of function/functor can be passed to it.

Comment: @Thomenson well, you must have an instance to call the member function on. If you have an instance, then don't you know the type (i.e. the specialisation of the template) of that instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I understand the problem. A class called 'some_class' (MyAlgorithm) supposed to have a reference to template (AlgorithmConsumer). Since 'some_class' requires only one method, the easiest way is to pass a reference to the function, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>


class MyAlgorithm
{
    std::function<void()> prepare;
public:
    explicit MyAlgorithm(std::function<void()> prepare)
        : prepare{prepare}
    {}

    void do_something()
    {
        if (prepare)
        {
            prepare();
        }

        std::cout << "I did something\n";
    }
};

template<typename T>
class AlgorithmConsumer
{
    MyAlgorithm algorithm;
public:
    AlgorithmConsumer()
        : algorithm([this](){prepare();})
    {}

    void prepare()
    {
        std::cout << "Preparing...\n";
    }

    void execute()
    {
        algorithm.do_something();
    }
};

int main()
{
    AlgorithmConsumer<int> ac;
    ac.execute();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope, this solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it without using `std::function`

```
struct B{ 


    template<class T>
    void CallTemplateFun(void (T::*funPtr)(), T& instance){

        (instance.*funPtr)();
    }


};

template<typename T>
class A{

    T t;
    B b;

public:

    A(T v) : t(v){}

    void print(){ std::cout << t << std::endl  ; }
};

int main(
{

    A<int> ai(5);
    B b;
    b.CallTemplateFun(&A<int>::print, ai);


    A<float> af(3.1428f);
    b.CallTemplateFun(&A<float>::print, af);


    return 0;
}
```